# LibGDX - draw bullet physics bounding box

Tags: libgdx, bullet-physics

I am very new to game development and I am trying to debug my 3d collision bounds. Could somebody give me an example on how to draw the collision bounds of an object in libGDX?

I assume it has something to do with `btIDebugDraw` but I can't find any examples on how to draw them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setDebugMode()` method of the `BulletWorld` class. The argument that you specify is an `int` depicting the mode. For example, you can use `world.setDebugMode(btIDebugDraw.DebugDrawModes.DBG_MAX_DEBUG_DRAW_MODE )` to draw every single debug option available. You can find a list of other modes from [Bullet Physic's documentation here](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtIDebugDraw.html).

Answer (score 3):

This approach works well for LibGDX 1.2.0

First of all you must create new instance of `DebugDrawer` and set debug mode you need:

```
debugDrawer = new DebugDrawer();
debugDrawer.setDebugMode(btIDebugDraw.DebugDrawModes.DBG_MAX_DEBUG_DRAW_MODE);
```

Set this drawer to your `btDynamicsWorld` instance:

```
world.setDebugDrawer(debugDrawer);
```

Display debug data in ApplicationAdapter.render() method:

```
debugDrawer.begin(camera);
world.debugDrawWorld();
debugDrawer.end();
```